# How can I call Html.Action from inside a @helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to show a list of details about an object, and all child objects of the parent, so I wrote this recursive helper.

When I try to run it I get this error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1928: 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper'
> does not contain a definition for 'Action' and the best extension
> method overload
> 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
> string, string, object)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Source Error:
>
> @Html.Action("_PDFUserStories", "Screen", new { screenID = screen.ID})

Before I was using a partial view and @Html.Action worked fine, but when I try to use a @Html.Action in a helper it does not work. Can I use @Html.Action in a helper? Here is the helper:

```
@helper ScreenDetails(UserStoriesApplication.Models.Screen screen)
{
<div style="page-break-after: always;">
    <div class="box col-12">
        <div class="box-header">
            <h2><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>@screen.Name</h2>
            <div class="box-icon">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @if (screen.filename != null)
    {
        <img class="img-responsive screenImage" src="~/Content/ScreenImages/@screen.filename" alt="Screen" />
    }
    <div class="story-details" id="story-details">
        @Html.Action("_PDFUserStories", "Screen", new { screenID = screen.ID })
    </div>
</div>

    foreach(var childScreen in screen.Screen1)
    {
       @ScreenDetails(childScreen)

    }

}
```

Comment: I have got it to work in a helper but I can't see what's wrong here.

Comment: But my helper is inside the view - I'll try putting it in a stand-alone file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a reason unknown to me, the 'Html' that comes with the Helper class is not the same as the 'Html' that comes with views. The Helper one is in the System.Web.WebPages.Html namespace, while the View one is in the System.Web.Mvc namespace. That's why it didn't have the methods you expected. However this can be easily fixed by passing in the Html object to your helper as a parameter. So you could change the signature of your ScreenDetails helper to

```
@helper ScreenDetails(UserStoriesApplication.Models.Screen screen,
     System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper Html)
```

then when you call it just pass in the view's Html object

```
@MyHelper.ScreenDetails(model, Html)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I'm surprised this is necessary though.